# String.Format like functionality in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, string

I'm looking for a built-in function/extended function in T-SQL for string manipulation similar to the `String.Format` method in .NET.

Answer (score 92):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use `FORMATMESSAGE`. eg.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(50) = 'World';
DECLARE @d INT = 123;
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hello %s, %d', @s, @d)
-- RETURNS 'Hello World, 123'
```

---

More examples from MSDN: [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql)

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Signed int %i, %d %i, %d, %+i, %+d, %+i, %+d', 5, -5, 50, -50, -11, -11, 11, 11);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Signed int with leading zero %020i', 5);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Signed int with leading zero 0 %020i', -55);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Unsigned int %u, %u', 50, -50);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Unsigned octal %o, %o', 50, -50);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Unsigned hexadecimal %x, %X, %X, %X, %x', 11, 11, -11, 50, -50);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Unsigned octal with prefix: %#o, %#o', 50, -50);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Unsigned hexadecimal with prefix: %#x, %#X, %#X, %X, %x', 11, 11, -11, 50, -50);
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hello %s!', 'TEST');
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hello %20s!', 'TEST');
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hello %-20s!', 'TEST');
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('Hello %20s!', 'TEST');
```

NOTES:

- Undocumented in 2012
- Limited to 2044 characters
- To escape the % sign, you need to double it.
- If you are logging errors in extended events, calling `FORMATMESSAGE` comes up as a (harmless) error

Comment: If you are using SQL 2012, you can use the [FORMAT function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) without all the above complication :)

Comment: This should have way more votes! Awesome find always avoided because assumed it would only work with built-in *`msg_number`*.

Comment: @Lankymart, bump! I agree this should be the accepted answer: simple, built-in and worked splendidly.

Comment: The documentation for 2012 shows only a msgid is supported on this function; 2014 is the first version that indicates a string may be supplied

Comment: very important to add that formatmessage have a length limit of 2044 characters

Comment: Any specific reason why SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('viw_system_%entity_%master_childattributes', @entity, @master) does not work.

Comment: @bijayk it only accepts specific placeholder names, eg, %s for strings, %i for ints.

Comment: Question is about `String.Format` not `printf`

Comment: @lostmylogin There is no `string.Format`-style functionality in T-SQL, this is the closest you'll get.

Comment: Is there a way to use a parameter more than once in the format string?

Answer (score 58):

take a look at [xp_sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175014.aspx). example below.

```
DECLARE @ret_string varchar (255)
EXEC xp_sprintf @ret_string OUTPUT, 
    'INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s)', 'table1', '1', '2'
PRINT @ret_string
```

Result looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 2)
```

---

Just found an issue with the max size (255 char limit) of the string with this so there is an [alternative function](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=65584) you can use:

```
create function dbo.fnSprintf (@s varchar(MAX), 
                @params varchar(MAX), @separator char(1) = ',')
returns varchar(MAX)
as
begin
declare @p varchar(MAX)
declare @paramlen int

set @params = @params + @separator
set @paramlen = len(@params)
while not @params = ''
begin
    set @p = left(@params+@separator, charindex(@separator, @params)-1)
    set @s = STUFF(@s, charindex('%s', @s), 2, @p)
    set @params = substring(@params, len(@p)+2, @paramlen)
end
return @s
end
```

To get the same result as above you call the function as follows:

```
print dbo.fnSprintf('INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s, %s)', 'table1,1,2', default)
```

Comment: Just an FYI if any of your params contains a comma then you are out of luck. If you happen to pass one by accident your going to have some troubles figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 16):

I have created a user defined function to mimic the string.format functionality.
You can use it.

[stringformat-in-sql](http://stringformat-in-sql.blogspot.com/)

UPDATE:
This version allows the user to change the delimitter.

```
-- DROP function will loose the security settings.
IF object_id('[dbo].[svfn_FormatString]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[svfn_FormatString]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svfn_FormatString]
(
    @Format NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Parameters NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ','
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    /*
        Name: [dbo].[svfn_FormatString]
        Creation Date: 12/18/2020

        Purpose: Returns the formatted string (Just like in C-Sharp)

        Input Parameters:   @Format         = The string to be Formatted
                            @Parameters     = The comma separated list of parameters
                            @Delimiter      = The delimitter to be used in the formatting process

        Format:             @Format         = N'Hi {0}, Welcome to our site {1}. Thank you {0}'
                            @Parameters     = N'Karthik,google.com'
                            @Delimiter      = ','           
        Examples:
            SELECT dbo.svfn_FormatString(N'Hi {0}, Welcome to our site {1}. Thank you {0}', N'Karthik,google.com', default)
            SELECT dbo.svfn_FormatString(N'Hi {0}, Welcome to our site {1}. Thank you {0}', N'Karthik;google.com', ';')
    */
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @ParamTable TABLE ( Id INT IDENTITY(0,1), Paramter VARCHAR(1000))

    SELECT @Message = @Format

    ;WITH CTE (StartPos, EndPos) AS
    (
        SELECT 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Parameters)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT EndPos + (LEN(@Delimiter)), CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Parameters, EndPos + (LEN(@Delimiter)))
        FROM CTE
        WHERE EndPos > 0
    )

    INSERT INTO @ParamTable ( Paramter )
    SELECT
        [Id] = SUBSTRING(@Parameters, StartPos, CASE WHEN EndPos > 0 THEN EndPos - StartPos ELSE 4000 END )
    FROM CTE

    UPDATE @ParamTable 
    SET 
        @Message = REPLACE(@Message, '{'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, Id) + '}', Paramter )

    RETURN @Message
END
```

Comment: I like this solution since I have reservations against using xp_ functions/SPs in production.  I used your code as a base and allowed for the passing in of the delimiter, which eliminates any concern about commas being used in the data.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way, but it has its limitations.  You can use the `FORMATMESSAGE()` function.  It allows you to format a string using formatting similar to the `printf()` function in C.

However, the biggest limitation is that it will only work with messages in the sys.messages table.  Here's an article about it: [microsoft_library_ms186788](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186788.aspx)

It's kind of a shame there isn't an easier way to do this, because there are times when you want to format a string/varchar in the database.  Hopefully you are only looking to format a string in a standard way and can use the `sys.messages` table.

Coincidentally, you could also use the `RAISERROR()` function with a very low severity, the documentation for raiseerror even mentions doing this, but the results are only printed.  So you wouldn't be able to do anything with the resulting value (from what I understand).

Good luck!

Comment: Understand this is an old answer but assumption about `FORMATMESSAGE()` is incorrect, however understandable because it is undocumented but it will accept any string as a first parameter, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30260729/692942) by [@g2server](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2293226/g2server).

Comment: @Lankymart You are correct - this is an old answer.  The ability to accept a string wasn't added until SQL 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Raw t-sql is limited to CHARINDEX(), PATINDEX(), REPLACE(), and SUBSTRING() for string manipulation.  But with sql server 2005 and later you can set up user defined functions that run in .Net, which means setting up a string.format() UDF shouldn't be too tough.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is small correction while calculating end position.

Here is correct function

```
**>>**IF OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[FormatString]', 'FN' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatString]
GO
/***************************************************
Object Name : FormatString
Purpose : Returns the formatted string.
Original Author : Karthik D V http://stringformat-in-sql.blogspot.com/
Sample Call:
SELECT dbo.FormatString ( N'Format {0} {1} {2} {0}', N'1,2,3' )
*******************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatString](
    @Format NVARCHAR(4000) ,
    @Parameters NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @Format NVARCHAR(4000), @Parameters NVARCHAR(4000) select @format='{0}{1}', @Parameters='hello,world'
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(400), @Delimiter CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @ParamTable TABLE ( ID INT IDENTITY(0,1), Parameter VARCHAR(1000) )
    Declare @startPos int, @endPos int
    SELECT @Message = @Format, @Delimiter = ','**>>**

    --handle first parameter
     set @endPos=CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Parameters)
    if (@endPos=0 and @Parameters is not null) --there is only one parameter
        insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) values(@Parameters)
    else begin
        insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) select substring(@Parameters,0,@endPos)
    end

    while @endPos>0
    Begin
        --insert a row for each parameter in the 
        set @startPos = @endPos + LEN(@Delimiter)
        set @endPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Parameters, @startPos)
        if (@endPos>0)
            insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) 
                select substring(@Parameters,@startPos,@endPos - @startPos)
            else
                insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) 
                select substring(@Parameters,@startPos,4000)            
    End

    UPDATE @ParamTable SET @Message = 
        REPLACE ( @Message, '{'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ID) + '}', Parameter )
    RETURN @Message
END
Go
grant execute,references on dbo.formatString to public
```

Answer (score 2):

One more idea.

Although this is not a universal solution - it is simple and works, at least for me :)

For one placeholder {0}:

```
create function dbo.Format1
(
    @String  nvarchar(4000),
    @Param0  sql_variant
)
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    declare @Null nvarchar(4) = N'NULL';

    return replace(@String, N'{0}', cast(isnull(@Param0, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));    
end
```

For two placeholders {0} and {1}:

```
create function dbo.Format2
(
    @String  nvarchar(4000),
    @Param0  sql_variant,
    @Param1  sql_variant
)
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    declare @Null nvarchar(4) = N'NULL';

    set @String = replace(@String, N'{0}', cast(isnull(@Param0, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));
       return     replace(@String, N'{1}', cast(isnull(@Param1, @Null) as nvarchar(4000))); 
end
```

For three placeholders {0}, {1} and {2}:

```
create function dbo.Format3
(
    @String  nvarchar(4000),
    @Param0  sql_variant,
    @Param1  sql_variant,
    @Param2  sql_variant
)
returns nvarchar(4000)
as
begin
    declare @Null nvarchar(4) = N'NULL';

    set @String = replace(@String, N'{0}', cast(isnull(@Param0, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));
    set @String = replace(@String, N'{1}', cast(isnull(@Param1, @Null) as nvarchar(4000))); 
       return     replace(@String, N'{2}', cast(isnull(@Param2, @Null) as nvarchar(4000)));
end
```

and so on...

Such an approach allows us to use these functions in SELECT statement and with parameters of nvarchar, number, bit and datetime datatypes.

For example:

```
declare @Param0 nvarchar(10) = N'IPSUM' ,
        @Param1 int          = 1234567  ,
        @Param2 datetime2(0) = getdate();

select dbo.Format3(N'Lorem {0} dolor, {1} elit at {2}', @Param0, @Param1, @Param2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no built in function similar to string.Format function of .NET is available in SQL server.

There is a function **FORMATMESSAGE()** in SQL server but it mimics to printf() function of C not string.Format function of .NET.

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE('This is the %s and this is the %s.', 'first variable', 'second variable') AS Result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version. Can be extended to accommodate more number of parameters and can extend formatting based on type. Currently only date and datetime types are formatted.

Example:

```
select dbo.FormatString('some string %s some int %s date %s','"abcd"',100,cast(getdate() as date),DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
select dbo.FormatString('some string %s some int %s date time %s','"abcd"',100,getdate(),DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

Output:

```
some string "abcd" some int 100 date 29-Apr-2017
some string "abcd" some int 100 date time 29-Apr-2017 19:40
```

Functions:

```
create function dbo.FormatValue(@param sql_variant)
returns nvarchar(100)
begin
/*
Tejasvi Hegde, 29-April-2017
Can extend formatting here.
*/
    declare @result nvarchar(100)

    if (SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@param,'BaseType') in ('date'))
    begin
       select @result = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), @param, 106), ' ', '-')
    end
    else  if (SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@param,'BaseType') in ('datetime','datetime2'))
    begin
       select @result = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), @param, 106), ' ', '-')+' '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@param,108)
    end
    else
    begin
       select @result = cast(@param as nvarchar(100))
    end
    return @result

/*
BaseType:
bigint
binary
char
date
datetime
datetime2
datetimeoffset
decimal
float
int
money
nchar
numeric
nvarchar
real
smalldatetime
smallint
smallmoney
time
tinyint
uniqueidentifier
varbinary
varchar
*/   

end;


create function dbo.FormatString(
    @format nvarchar(4000)
    ,@param1 sql_variant = null
    ,@param2 sql_variant = null
    ,@param3 sql_variant = null
    ,@param4 sql_variant = null
    ,@param5 sql_variant = null
    )
returns nvarchar(4000)
begin
/*
Tejasvi Hegde, 29-April-2017

select dbo.FormatString('some string value %s some int %s date %s','"abcd"',100,cast(getdate() as date),DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
select dbo.FormatString('some string value %s some int %s date time %s','"abcd"',100,getdate(),DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
*/

    declare @result nvarchar(4000)

    select @param1 = dbo.formatValue(@param1)
    ,@param2 = dbo.formatValue(@param2)
    ,@param3 = dbo.formatValue(@param3)
    ,@param4 = dbo.formatValue(@param4)
    ,@param5 = dbo.formatValue(@param5)

    select @param2 = cast(@param2 as nvarchar)
    EXEC xp_sprintf @result OUTPUT,@format , @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5

    return @result

end;
```

Comment: Simplest answer for SQL Server 2008+.  Keeps inputs as separate parameters. Uses xp_sprintf function and can be extended easily.

xp_sprintf - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-sprintf-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

here's what I found with my experiments using the built-in

FORMATMESSAGE() function

```
sp_addmessage @msgnum=50001,@severity=1,@msgText='Hello %s you are #%d',@replace='replace'
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE(50001, 'Table1', 5)
```

when you call up sp_addmessage, your message template gets stored into the system table master.dbo.sysmessages (verified on SQLServer 2000).

You must manage addition and removal of template strings from the table  yourself, which is awkward if all you really want is output a quick message to the results screen.

The solution provided by Kathik DV, looks interesting but doesn't work with SQL Server 2000, so i altered it a bit, and this version should work with all versions of SQL Server:

```
IF OBJECT_ID( N'[dbo].[FormatString]', 'FN' ) IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatString]
GO
/***************************************************
Object Name : FormatString
Purpose : Returns the formatted string.
Original Author : Karthik D V http://stringformat-in-sql.blogspot.com/
Sample Call:
SELECT dbo.FormatString ( N'Format {0} {1} {2} {0}', N'1,2,3' )
*******************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FormatString](
@Format NVARCHAR(4000) ,
@Parameters NVARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    --DECLARE @Format NVARCHAR(4000), @Parameters NVARCHAR(4000) select @format='{0}{1}', @Parameters='hello,world'
    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(400), @Delimiter CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @ParamTable TABLE ( ID INT IDENTITY(0,1), Parameter VARCHAR(1000) )
    Declare @startPos int, @endPos int
    SELECT @Message = @Format, @Delimiter = ','

    --handle first parameter
     set @endPos=CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Parameters)
    if (@endPos=0 and @Parameters is not null) --there is only one parameter
        insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) values(@Parameters)
    else begin
        insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) select substring(@Parameters,0,@endPos)
    end

    while @endPos>0
    Begin
        --insert a row for each parameter in the 
        set @startPos = @endPos + LEN(@Delimiter)
        set @endPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@Parameters, @startPos)
        if (@endPos>0)
            insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) select substring(@Parameters,@startPos,@endPos)
        else
            insert into @ParamTable (Parameter) select substring(@Parameters,@startPos,4000)            
    End

    UPDATE @ParamTable SET @Message = REPLACE ( @Message, '{'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ID) + '}', Parameter )
    RETURN @Message
END
Go
    grant execute,references on dbo.formatString to public
```

Usage:

```
print dbo.formatString('hello {0}... you are {1}','world,good')
--result: hello world... you are good
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this doesn't really exist (although you can of course write your own).  There is an open connect bug for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3130221, which as of this writing has just 1 vote.

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly, but I would check out some of the [articles](http://www.simple-talk.com/author/robyn-page-and-phil-factor/) on string handling (amongst other things) by "Phil Factor" (geddit?) on Simple Talk.

Answer (score -3):

this is bad approach. you should work with assembly dll's, in which will do the same for you with better performance.