# How to format the SQL PRINT messages -- a kind of C printf()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

... Well, not exactly only for `PRINT`. I need to assign a string variable the value that mixes explicit substrings with integer values (and possibly with other type values). The goal is to get the string for logging.

So far, I use the code like:

```
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(1000)
...
SET @msg = @procname + 'result = ' + CAST(@result AS nvarchar(5))
                     + '; error = ' + CAST(@error AS nvarchar(5))
```

where the `@procname` is a string like `sp_my_proc:`, and the `@result` and the `@error` are integer variables. The result should look like (no extra spaces around the numbers, just the minimum length):

```
sp_my_proc: result = 3; error = 0
```

The above approach works, but... Is there any better way for converting an integer variable to the string than `CAST(@result AS nvarchar(5))`? (Consider the magic number 5 being a minor detail to be ignored.)

How do you solve the problem of generating such strings in your code?

Thanks, Petr

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 there is `FORMAT`

Comment: +1 Thanks for the `FORMAT`. Just curious why they reversed the format string and the value in comparison with other languages. I am using SQL 2008 R2 -- no luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL-Server you can use STR() function
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189527.aspx
The default value for 'length' parameter is 10. Since an integer variable is never longer than 10 symbols (you'd have an overflow) this will always work without errors:

```
declare @test int
set @test = 333333333
select STR(@test)
```

Also, take a look at
[String.Format like functionality in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159554/string-format-like-functionality-in-t-sql)

Comment: +1 for the http://stackoverflow.com/a/1153194/1346705 link. But the `STR()` is not suitable. It fills the number by spaces. If the len is smaller than needed, it converts to `***`.