# Printing variables and messages in T-Sql in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following code

```
create procedure math_table1(@num int, @i int)
as
begin
    declare @b int
    set @b = 1 
    while (@b <= @i)
    begin
        print @num 
        print '*'
        print @b 
        print '='
        print  @num * @b;
        set @b = @b + 1;
    end
end
```

For input `5, 10` I get the following type of output:

```
5
*
1
=
5
```

I want to modify my code to get the following type of output:

```
5*1=5
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using different `print` statements use one `print` statement and append the `symbols`. Try this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Math_table1 (@num INT,
                             @i   INT)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @b INT
      SET @b=1

      WHILE( @b <= @i )
        BEGIN
            PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @num) + '*'
                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @b) + '='
                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @num*@b);

            SET @b=@b + 1;
        END
  END

EXEC Math_table1 5,10
```

**Result**

```
5*1=5
5*2=10
5*3=15
5*4=20
5*5=25
5*6=30
5*7=35
5*8=40
5*9=45
5*10=50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create procedure math_table1 (@num int, @i int)
as
begin   
    declare @r int, @b int = 1;
    while (@b <= @i)
    begin
        set @r = @num * @b;
        raiserror ('%d * %d = %d', 0, 1, @num, @b, @r) with nowait;
        set @b = @b + 1;
    end
end
```

[PRINT vs RAISERROR](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/19/print-vs-raiserror/)

... or use your own "Format" function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28240424/623190)

```
print dbo.Format3('{0} * {1} = {2}', 2, 3, 6);
```